# What's the deal with amarok on Debian?

Tags: debian, package-management, amarok

There used to be an amarok package for Debian:

https://wiki.debian.org/Amarok

and yet, if you visit that page and follow the link, the package seems to be gone. And when I `apt search amarok` - I find nothing (on Devuan Deadalus, i.e. ~= Debian 12.0).

Was it removed from Debian? Or just abandoned? And - how do people typically install amarok on Debian these days?

Comment: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=935022 (starting from: https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/amarok )

Answer (score 1):

As the link provided by @A.B. suggests - Amarok seems to be somewhat abandoned, with no proper release since 2018 and the last "preview release" being 2 years ago. With no acceptable Qt5-based release - Debian have dropped the package.

Too bad :-(

Comment: a "successor in spirit" is `clementine`.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Just [asked about a successor on SR.SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/87748/15631). But - Clementine also [seems abandoned](https://www.clementine-player.org/) - no news since 2016.

Comment: It's not abandoned, they just haven't done a proper version increase and release (which I find a bummer), so currently every distro is shipping "clementine 1.4 release candidate N" or so